# java forms inheritance calls wrong method from super constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I have four class objects, two handler classes, a base form class and a derived form class.

The handler class contains the Start method:

```
public void Start(int BodyFontSize)
{
 pForm = new TT_FORM(pParent
                    ,false
                    ,BodyFontSize
                    );
 ShowForm();
}
```

This calls the base form constructor:

```
public TT_FORM(clsHCI  Parent
              ,boolean Blocking
              ,int     FontSize
              )
{
 super(new javax.swing.JFrame()
      ,Blocking
      );
 System.out.println("TT_FORM constructor");
 m_pParent = Parent;
 createFormItems();
 sizeForm(FontSize);
 ...
 ...
}
```

where the methods createFormItems and sizeForm are defined and also print an entry statement.
Calling the handler Start method produces the expected output:
TT_FORM constructor
TT_FORM createFormItems
TT_FORM sizeForm

I now introduce the second handler class with the method:

```
 public void Start(int BodyFontSize)
 {
  pForm = new TT_START(pParent
                      ,BodyFontSize
                  );
  ShowForm();
 }
```

This calls the constructor of the derived form:

```
public class TT_START extends    TT_FORM
                      implements ActionListener
{
 private static final long    serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private              clsHCI  m_pParent;

 public TT_START(clsHCI Parent
                ,int FontSize
                )
 {
  super(Parent, true, FontSize);
  System.out.println("TT_START constructor");
  m_pParent = Parent;
  createFormItems();
  sizeForm(FontSize);
 }
```

where the methods createFormItems and sizeForm are defined within the derived class and print entry statements.

Calling this handler Start method produces the output:
TT_FORM constructor
TT_FORM createFormItems
TT_START sizeForm

The output I was expecting was:
TT_FORM constructor
TT_FORM createFormItems
TT_FORM sizeForm
TT_START constructor
TT_START createFormItems
TT_START sizeForm

Can anyone explain why this calling sequence differs from my expectation?
What changes do I need to get the calling sequence I require?

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem - ideally following normal Java naming conventions, too...

Comment: You should explicitly invoke parent class methods via [super keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Answer (score 0):

After some more work I resolved the issue and have realised that:
1. I had declared createFormItems private, since it was only called from the constructor.  This was called as expected from the super constructor.
2. I had declared sizeForm public so that it could be also called from the handler.  This was not invoked from the call in the constructor.

sizeForm was over-ridden by the sub-class but is called from within the parent class constructor.  This is not the way that I expected inheritance to operate.
The general rule has to be that all methods called by a constructor have to be private and an additional public method is required for external usage.